# Using python's context manager to get the order of operations inside a context

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager

I would like to create a context manager that is used as such:

```py
    with my_context_manager():
        add(1, 2)
        divide(3, 4)
        multiply(5, 6)
```

That would return the order of functions called within the context - i.e. something like

```
[(add, (1, 2)), (divide, (3, 4)), (multiply, (5, 6))]
```

Is this possible? A quick attempt at using inspect.stack() failed for me given I only see the multiply call ...

Comment: How would the context manager "return" the order of function calls -- in other words, how do you imagine being able to access the list you describe?  A context manager function returns the context when the context is entered (before anything has happened in it), and after the context closes the object goes out of scope.  What I think you might want is some kind of decorator that logs function calls.

Comment: Your context manager could use `sys.settrace()` to turn on tracing in `__enter__()`, and turn it back off in `__exit__()`.  You would be informed of every function call that was made, although getting the name and parameters like you show would still be some work.

Comment: @jasonharper - will give it a try thank you for the suggestion